# Is there a way to make Launch4j 3.12 use a bundled OpenJDK instead of Oracle JRE?

Tags: java, launch4j

I am using **Launch4j 3.12** to create a launcher for a jar (using `launch4jc.exe` from the command line) and then **NSIS** to create an installer that also bundles OpenJDK in the installer.

The problem is Launch4j needs Oracle JRE installed on the PC to be able to run. Is there a command line argument to tell Launch4j to use OpenJDK installed at a custom location, so that I don't need to have Oracle JRE installed on my PC?

I am not using any fancy command line arguments for the installer creation, it's just:

`launch4jc.exe launcher-config.xml`

And the error I get is this:

`launch4j: This application requires a Java Runtime Environment 1.6.0 - 1.8.9`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to use OpenJDK as bundled runtime, but you are using methods that are available only in normal Java. Also you have to download OpenJDK from its site: https://openjdk.java.net/install/ Don’t forget change normal java library for a OpenJDK library.

Comment: It's not me. It's the actual Launch4j application that might be using them.

Comment: So you have to set it to do not use it. It should be somewhere in setting Java version. BTW: If you use NetBeans it can make .exe file with bundled Java by one click. Project settings -> distribution -> enable it -> and then distribute as exe

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, but as long as you use this program you must install oracle JRE.  I hope your problem is resolved